# PostgreSQL - Better to join with a TIMESTAMP field, or should I convert to a unix_timestamp (int) to join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, query-optimization, inner-join

I am creating a join, and as part of this join I am using a timestamp field to join with. Performance wise, would I be better converting both timestamps to a unix_timestamp, so that the join is using a integer? Or would I be better leaving as is.

Comment: A timestamp **is** internally a big (integer)

Comment: Oh and this: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: On a side note, joining on a `TIMESTAMP` field smells fishy, akin to comparing floats for equality. Two timestamps could be different though close enough to be considered equal for practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect any noticeable performance difference depending on whether the datatype of the column is `timestamp` or `integer`. As commented by a_horse_with_no_name, a timestamp is internally stored as an integer anyway.

An important thing to note: performance-wise, you want to use the raw data directly, without applying any transformation.

A predicate that uses functions makes the query non-SARGable, meaning that the database cannot take advantage of an index, even if there is one available:

```
extract(epoch from t1.timestamp) = extract(epoch from t2.timestamp)
```

Instead, you do want to use the column values directly:

```
t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the Horse's comment above, internally a Postgres `timestamp` and a numeric UNIX timestamp may be implemented very similarly under the hood.  What is not the same between them is that the UNIX timestamp may pose presentation problems for you, because in your reporting you may have to often convert that to a formal date-time based timestamp.  So, using a proper `timestamp` may have benefits from a reporting point of view.